# Postgres relations for owner and users

Tags: postgresql

I'm doing an exercise to learn database designs. This is some kind of fantasy soccer teams. I have this initial tables, `users` and `teams`. One team can have many users and a user can join and belongs to one team.

```
   USERS
PK id
FK team_id -> TEAMS.id
   username

   TEAMS
PK id
   name
```

But I also want to allow users to create their own teams if they don't want to join another team. What if I added `owner_id` in `teams` table?

```
   TEAMS
PK id
FK owner_id -> USERS.id
   name
```

I feel like this is not the right way to do. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Is your problem that you want to assert that an owner of a team must also be a member of this team? Or can one a team and be a member of another or none?

Comment: Yes, you're right. An `owner` of the team must also be a member of this team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a flag in `users` that indicates if the user owns the team they're a member of and a partial unique index to restrict this flag only being set once for a team.

```
CREATE TABLE teams
             (id serial,
              owner_id integer,
              PRIMARY KEY (id));

CREATE TABLE users
             (id serial,
              team_id integer
                      NOT NULL,
              is_owner boolean
                       NOT NULL
                       DEFAULT FALSE,
              PRIMARY KEY (id),
              FOREIGN KEY (team_id)
                           REFERENCES teams
                                      (id));

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX users_team_id_is_owner
                    ON users
                       (team_id)
                    WHERE is_owner;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=8abaa7c1f4748c9eb9423e825f1271ea)
The index only includes the row that satisfy the `WHERE` clause, thus all of them have the flag `is_owner` set to `true`. Within that subset of rows the `team_id` must be unique which follows that there can not be any two rows with the same `team_id` and `is_owner` set to `true`.

To ensure a user must be a member of a team, set the `team_id` to be `NOT NULL`.

There can be teams without owners in that schema though. But as I understood your question, that is OK.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One more question though, what if I use `role` or `permission` table instead? And grant a `user` who own a team as a `owner` in `user_roles` ManyToMany table.

Comment: @Rario: If the team ID is in that table too, say like `role_user_teams(role_id, user_id, team_id)`, you can also use a partial index analog to my answer. The `WHERE` clause needs to be amended to filter for the ID of the owner role instead of the flag. If the design you have in mind is different however, better ask a new question describing that design in detail. Discussing such followups in detail isn't what comments are for here.